# Where do I found Joomla 1.0

Tags: joomla

My friend website is running on Joomla-1.0 & now he wants to migrate to Joomla-2.5.4. I have found many useful links for accomplish this job but before do it live I want a demo on my localhost, I searched for Joomla-1.0 (**EXACTLY 1.0**) for download but not found.

Do somebody knows where could I download exactly **Joomla-1.0**?

Thanks.

Comment: Not even a point release?! (Like [1.0.15](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseView&release_id=6828)? Why do you even want it to be the precise point release? Wouldn't it be easier to just use what you can get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get why you want to use 1.0, I mean the support is stopped by the community and you'll encounter (a lot) of errors since Joomla 1.0 is based on a different version of PHP ... but if you insist you'll have to take a look in the underground(unofficial) websites ...

Check this : http://mirror.phil-taylor.com

Comment: If you read his question you will see that he wants it to test the migration process offline before he does it on the live site ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a backup of his website that is online and install it on a localhost. I have no idea where you can find Joomla 1.0 but using a replica of your current site would be much better.

Found [Joomla 1.0.15](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseView&release_id=6828)

Comment: @MuhammadSajid see my answer, updated with a link to the download page that Joomla Code still provide